# How do I use the github api to follow api to help authenicated users follow others

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, axios, github-api

I want my reactJS application to have a button where the logged-in user can follow the desired GitHub user once clicked. When I click the button it sends the request but I get a 404 error that says "ailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"
I tried looking at the Github API docs but I don't understand what I should do differently.

here is my request in Javascript

```
axios.put(`https://api.github.com/users/${the logged in user.username}/following`,{
      'username':`${the user I want to follower's username}`
    })
    .then(res => console.log(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get exactly what your are trying to get from the api, but looking your axios req seems like the METHOD (PUT => GET) of the request is wrong.

First, check the available api endpoints:
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/endpoints-available-for-github-apps#users

Second,
If you are trying to build a button which when clicked "FOLLOW" another username, I'm afraid that is not posible. At least looking on the docs there isn't such endpoint available.